# How to change list depend in string value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to print list depend on input string

The code like this:

```
A1 = [1,2]
B1 = [2,3]

p = input("A1/B1 : ")

print(p)
#if input is "A1" it will print A1 list or "A2" it will print A2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store your data in a `dict` and get it to retrieve the data you want:

```py
d = {'A1': [1,2], 'B1': [2,3]}

p = input("A1/B1 : ")

element = d.get(p, None)
if element is None:
    print("Sorry, not found")
else:
    print(element)
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe you misunderstanding. i already edit it

Comment: Yes, maybe I did misunderstand. What exact outputs are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like?

```py
if p == 'A1':
  print(A1)
elif p == 'A2':
  print(A2)
else:
  print('Your answer must be A1 or A1')
```