# How to print list name based on string input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to call list depend on string input

The code example:

```
day = [1,7]
month = [1,12]

ip = input("day or month :")

print(
#example the input is "day", i want to print day[list]/ variable declared before
)
```

We can use

```
if p == "day":
    print(day)
```

And month
but it need much time, if we have more properties. What's most effective method to print list depend on string input?

Comment: Are you guys doing the [same homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72154873/how-to-change-list-depend-in-string-value) or what :D

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionaries!

```
my_dict_of_lists = {
    'day': list(range(1, 32)),
    'month': list(range(1, 13)),
}

print(my_dict_of_lists['day'])
```